# Replace fragment of one viewpager with fragment of another viewpager in the same activity back key pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 2 viewpagers: `swipeViewPager` and `nonSwipeViewPager` in `MainActivity`

In `swipeableViewPager`, I have fragments: `homeFragmentFirst` and `homeFragmentSecond`

In `nonSwipeableViewPager`, I have fragments: `AppleFragment` , `MangoFragment`, `GrapesFragment` and `CherryFragment`

First I want `swipeableViewPager` to be viewed in `MainActivity`. So I have set `setVisibility` of `nonSwipeableViewPager` as `GONE`.
After selecting an item from the `drawer`, I `setVisibility` of `swipeableViewPager` as `GONE` and of `nonSwipeableViewPager` as `Visible`.
By this, I open `AppleFragment`

**Situation:**
Suppose, I selected *Grapes* from drawer, `GrapesFragment` opens.
I do my some stuff there. And then when I press back button, the app closes i.e. the `MainActivity` closes.

What I want is when back button is pressed, I want to again bring back `homeFragmentFirst` from `swipeableViewPager`.

I have tried below code in `GrapesFragment`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // Do some operations here
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    mainActivity.swipeHomeViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mainActivity.nonSwipeHomeViewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. I added following in `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (nonSwipeHomeViewPager.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        nonSwipeHomeViewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        swipeHomeViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        swipeHomeViewPager.setCurrentItem(0,true);
    } else if (swipeHomeViewPager.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are such a scholar.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement backstack for the fragments (while adding / replacing fragment) add it to backstack. the back press will automatically take you to previous fragment.

otherwise you need to override OnBackPressed method to handle with your own logic.

Comment: I think backstack works when you want to go back to previous fragment in the same viewpager. But I want to go back to different fragment in different viewpager.
I've tried to override OnBackPressed, but I am not able to do it.